# problems with converting class to factor in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to combine dataframes and unify the classes of columns between them.

I have a problem with note being about to convert one column to a factor.

I've tried converting the dataframe using  as.dataframe and converting the column using as.factor.

I have dataframes a,b,c and list

```
b$cat2 <-list[match (b$` Description`, list$Var1),"cat2",]
b2 <-b[,c("Number", "DOB", "Gender", "cat2"),]


colnames (b2) <- c ("Number", "DOB","Gender", "group" )

b2 <- as.data.frame (b2)

a$group <- as.factor (a$group)
class (b2$group )

 [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

b2$group <- as.factor (b2$group)
Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace


#combine a and b2 
combo <- rbind (a, b2)
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = list(cat2 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: The issue would be that the `group` column in 'b2' is itself a data.frame/tbl_df`..  If it is a single column dataframe, try ``b2$group <-factor( unlist(b2$group))`

Comment: Fantastic! Appreciate your help so much!

Comment: If you could edit this into a much simpler example that only illustrates the problem that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `class`, the column itself is a `tbl_df/data.frame`.  According to `factor` the input argument 'x' is a `vector`

> x - a vector of data, usually taking a small number of distinct
>   values.

Assuming that it is a single column data.frame, we can `unlist` and convert it to `factor`

```
b2$group <- factor( unlist(b2$group))
```

Or use extraction with `[[`

```
b2$group <- factor(b2$group[[1]])
```

Comment: Alternatively could use pull().